# AngularJS - factory is an empty object

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS - I can't figure out why I get the error `mainDataService.refreshStatus is not a function` in the `$scope.clickMe` function. I see the `mainDataService` variable is an empty object besides its initialization. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
    var mainDataService = {};

    var firstModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

    (function () {
        var mainDataServiceInjectParams = ['$http', '$q'];

        var mainFactory = function ($http, $q) {
            mainDataService.refreshStatus = function (id) {
                return $http.get('/api/values/' + id).then(function (results) {
                    return results.data;
                });
            };

            return mainDataService;
        };


        mainFactory.$inject = mainDataServiceInjectParams;
        firstModule = firstModule.factory('mainService', mainFactory);
    }());

    firstModule.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.TST = '1';

        $scope.clickMe = function (id) {
            mainDataService.refreshStatus(id).then(function (results) {
                $scope.TST = results;
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the dependency injection mechanism to load your own services.

Put the `mainDataService` declaration in a local scope and inject the `mainService` into `myCtrl`:

```
var firstModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

(function () {
    var mainDataServiceInjectParams = ['$http', '$q'];

    var mainFactory = function ($http, $q) {
        var mainDataService = {};
        mainDataService.refreshStatus = function (id) {
            return $http.get('/api/values/' + id).then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };

        return mainDataService;
    };


    mainFactory.$inject = mainDataServiceInjectParams;
    firstModule = firstModule.factory('mainService', mainFactory);
}());

firstModule.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, mainService) {
    $scope.TST = '1';

    $scope.clickMe = function (id) {
        mainService.refreshStatus(id).then(function (results) {
            $scope.TST = results;
        });
    }
});
```

Even better, you should explicitly assign the dependencies into the controller, so that your code still works after minifcation (as you already did it for the service):

```
firstModule.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'mainService'];
function myCtrl($scope, $http, mainService) {
    $scope.TST = '1';

    $scope.clickMe = function (id) {
        mainService.refreshStatus(id).then(function (results) {
            $scope.TST = results;
        });
    }
});
```

As you see, if you use normal function definitions, you can make use the function hoisting of Javascript and write the functions at the end while having the relevant code at the top. It's the other way round as in your example of the service.

Answer (score 1):

Supply  mainService to controller

```
firstModule.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, mainService) {
```

and then use it in the function

```
mainService.refreshStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you immediately invoked function is not invoked so mainDataService still reference the object you set at the first line

```
(function(){})()
```

rather than

```
(function(){}())
```